# Unity GetComponent for multiple scrips

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm implementing a weapon equip logic for my game.
I've got scriptable objects for the weapons which I can equip in my inventory.
For the weapons to actually work, I'm calling an Attack() Method on my ActiveWeapon script which each individual weapon script has. the ActiveWeapon script has the current active weapon stored as currentActiveWeapon. To get the right weapon on the currentActiveWeapon slot, I'm checking each weapon for it's object name and compare it to it's SO name. So if I have a GameObject called Sword with the script Sword on it, I'm checking if gameObject.name == SO.name. If so I equip it.
The problem is that I have to get each individual weapon script to equip the object.
It would be helpful to just look for a script on the object and equip that instead of specifically searching for one
Sorry if it's hard to understand my question

Here's the [hierachy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fILLL.png) of my objects

And that's the piece of code
the foreach loop is checking for the child objects of ActiveWeapon (for me it's Sword and Bow)
the if statement is checking for equality of the two names
and then here just the Sword script can be applied

```
        Transform parent = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<ActiveWeapon>().transform;

        foreach(Transform child in parent)
        {
            if(child.name == weapon.name)
            {
                activeWeapon.currentActiveWeapon = child.GetComponent<Sword>();
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is why we do inheritance or use interfaces, so you can just call "Attack" on whatever the heck it is rather than trying to find the specific one for the weapon

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your weapons have some shared functionality (which they all should have), you can use something called Interfaces. Basically it's a "template" to scripts to follow, and then when you need a script of a weapon, you can GetComponent the Interface:

```
IWeapon weapon = obj.GetComponent<IWeapon>();
weapon.Fire();
```

For example ^

Comment: I actually have an IWeapon Interface, but I listened to a guy in a tutorial and he wrote (currentActiveWeapon as IWeapon).Attack(); . Is that wrong then?

Comment: @Spacter this works as well, it's similar yet different. Both are good. What the guy in the tutorial did was cast the `IWeapon` type on the `currentActiveWeapon` variable, so now you can access the Attack method without knowing the actual type of the weapon.